# Regular expression metacharacters \w and \pL in PHP

Tags: php, regex

In version 5.3.4 - 5.5.0beta1, are `\w` and `\pL` equivalent?

```
 <?php
preg_match_all('#\w#u','سیب',$f);
var_dump($f);

preg_match_all('#\pL#u','سیب',$f);
var_dump($f);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "س"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "ی"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "ب"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "س"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "ی"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "ب"
  }
}
```

[Try the above snippet in the Online PHP shell](http://3v4l.org/o8m0X#v534)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like when you use the `u` modifier in PCRE regular expressions, PHP is also setting `PCRE_UCP` flag in addition to `PCRE_UTF8` flag, causing Unicode properties to be introduced into `\w` and the other POSIX character classes, instead of just the default ASCII characters. From the [man page on PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> PCRE_UCP
>
> This option changes the way PCRE processes \B, \b, \D, \d, \S, \s,  \W,
>   \w,  and  some  of  the POSIX character classes. By default, only ASCII
>   characters are recognized, but if PCRE_UCP is set,  Unicode  properties
>   are  used instead to classify characters.

This is then [confirmed in the PHP source code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c) (lines 366-372), where we see this:

```
        case 'u':   coptions |= PCRE_UTF8;
/* In  PCRE,  by  default, \d, \D, \s, \S, \w, and \W recognize only ASCII
   characters, even in UTF-8 mode. However, this can be changed by setting
   the PCRE_UCP option. */
#ifdef PCRE_UCP
                    coptions |= PCRE_UCP;
#endif
```

So, from the same man page that I linked above, you'll see that when `PCRE_UCP` is set, the character classes become:

> \d  any character that \p{Nd} matches (decimal digit)
>
> \s  any character that \p{Z} matches, plus HT, LF, FF, CR
>
> \w  any character that \p{L} or \p{N} matches, plus underscore

Comment: Perfect answer. Turning on the u flag in php is like adding (*UCP)(*UTF8) at the front of your regex. Sadly as of PCRE 8.34 there's no way to turn off PCRE_UCP inline. I say "sadly" because this makes \w run slower, as per the PCRE manual: "Matching characters by Unicode property is not fast, because PCRE has to do a multistage table lookup in order to find a character's property. That is why the traditional escape sequences such as \d and \w do not use Unicode properties in PCRE by default, though you can make them do so by setting the PCRE_UCP option or by starting the pattern with (*UCP)"

Comment: Actually, there is one workaround in order to have UTF8 without UCP: set UTF8 inline, as opposed to using the u flag. For instance: "~(*UTF8)\w+~"  This makes sure that unicode mode is turned on but \w does not match \p{L}